# How to modularize complex view using vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

After couple of month using vuex, I'm not sure that I'm using this in the right way.

My main question is, **How should I modularize states?**

For example :

I have a view to create and edit a resource (post). To **create** or **update** a post I need some API calls to fetch some data (like list of all available categories and tags). **where should I store them?** in *vuex/modules/post.js?* Or in a dedicated module like *vuex/modules/tags.js* and *vuex/moduels/categories.js*?

I'm storing post's tags and categories in *vuex/modules/post.js* but how about all of other resources that are needed in order to modify a resource (Like all of available tags and categories to be selected by the user )?

How about list of posts? Should I store list of posts in *vuex/modules/post* or in a dedicated *vuex/modules/posts-list.js*?

**Should every view have it's own module?**

*// vuex/modules/post.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Axios from 'axios'

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        title: null,
        slug: null,
        tags: [],
        categories: [],
        meta: {},
        excerpt: null,
        content: null,
        comments: []
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_TITLE(state, title) {
            state.title = title;
        },
        SET_SLUG(state, slug) {
            state.slug = slug;
        },
        SET_EXCERPT(state, excerpt) {
            state.excerpt = excerpt;
        },
        SET_CONTENT(state, content) {
            state.excerpt = content;
        },


        ADD_TAG(state, tag) {
            state.tags.unshift(tag)
        },
        REMOVE_TAG(state, index) {
            Vue.delete(state.tags, index);
        },
        SET_TAGS(state, tags) {
            state.tags = tags;
        },


        ADD_CATEGORY(state, category) {
            state.categories.unshift(category)
        },
        REMOVE_CATEGORY(state, index) {
            Vue.delete(state.categories, index);
        },
        SET_CATEGORIES(state, categories) {
            state.categories = categories;
        },


        ADD_META(state, {key, value}) {
            Vue.set(state.meta, key, value)
        },
        REMOVE_META(state, key) {
            Vue.delete(state.meta, key);
        },
        UPDATE_META(state, {key, value}) {
            state.meta[key] = value;
        },
        SET_META(state, meta) {
            state.meta = meta;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        save({state}) {
            Axios.post('http://myapi.com/posts', state);
        },
        async load({commit}, id) {
            const {data} = await Axios.get(`http://myapi.com/posts/${id}`);
            commit('SET_TITLE', data.title);
            commit('SET_SLUG', data.slug);
            commit('SET_EXCERPT', data.excerpt);
            commit('SET_CONTENT', data.content);
            commit('SET_TAGS', data.tags);
            commit('SET_CATEGORIES', data.categories);
            commit('SET_META', data.meta);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's completely up to you. I would store all domain related data (such as post tags, categories, posts itself) in dedicated module. But if i had another domain (for example products) i woluld create another module (products.js) that would have own tags, categories etc.

Thanks to `Vuex` namespaced modules it would be clear which tags do you want to access:

```
// get post tags
this.$store.getters["post/tags"];
{ ...mapGetters("post", ["tags"]) }

// get products tags
this.$store.getter["products/tags"];
{ ...mapGetters("products", ["tags"]) }
```